# Add onClicked handler to browser action without popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm starting out with Chrome Extensions.

My extension has 2 `content_scripts` which are executed on page load. I'd like to add an `onClicked` handler for my browser action from inside one of these JS files.

Basically what I want to do is [`chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html) but I've read in a similar question that this only works inside of a popup html file. I'm not using a popup file because I don't currently need one, and I need my JS to run in the global scope (as it does without a `default_popup`).

Here's my `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Foo",
  "description": "Foo description.",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "permissions":[
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery1.9.1.min.js", "foo.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Sorry but my googling skills couldn't find how to do this. Is there a way to attach an `onClicked` handler to my browser action or do I need an html popup for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decided to just move my overly long comment to an answer.

If you have a popup defined then the `onClicked` event is never fired, but it works just fine without one. Just pop the handler into your background page and it should work just fine. Be aware that `chrome.browserAction`, as well as just about every other `chrome.*` API, cannot be accessed from a `content script`, so you will require the use of a [`background`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) or [`event`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html) page.

Comment: actually you can use some `chrome.*` API methods like `chrome.extension` https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: @Less That is why I said "Just about" since the ones you can use are very limited.